# What word means centered about death?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm writing an essay about Don DiLillo's novel *White Noise*, and would like to explore Murray Jay Siskand's fascination with death.  The particular word I'm looking for means "death-centric", to fit in the topic sentence

"Furthermore, the consumerist society that envelops Siskind results in his `<word goes here>` viewpoint of his surroundings."

Failing that, is there a way to rework this sentence as to allow for an elegant focus on his death-centric viewpoint?

Comment: Death-centric is perfectly indicative of what you want to convey,however, the popular philosophical term is thanatocentric/thanatocentricism.

Comment: I'd rather rework the sentence to "Furthermore, the consumerist society that envelops Siskind causes him to take a view of his surroundings that is entirely centred on death."  Or something.  I don't think it's a good idea to use an obscure philosophical term that your readers might not know when you can rephrase the sentence so it's all in plain English, even if the English sentence is longer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `...results in the viewpoint of his surroundings being <word>` or `...results in his <word> view of his surroundings`?

Comment: Is "White Noise" the book the same as "White Noise" the movie. It is an excellent movie.

Comment: @BlessedGeek definitely not the same thing. The book is by Don Delillo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The combining form *thanat-* (or *thanato-*), meaning *death*, with the combining form *-centric*, gives you *thanatocentric* -- literally, *centered on death*.

Comment: Honestly, I find *death-centered* preferable to *thanatocentric*, if for not other reason that even if I can stem it, most people can't. Not that forming fancy words based on classical roots is some moribund art or anything: I just like the English one in this case.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to say exactly the same thing expressed in another language??

Comment: thanatocentric is unlikely to be understood by a general reader. Morbid and macabre are much better words.

Comment: Both morbid and macabre have strong connotations that might not match what the OP is going for, in which case a more "academic" word might work better.  Without knowing anything about the background material it's hard to judge.

Comment: Isn't it a sin to mix Latin with Greek like this?

Comment: @JackAidley: The likelihood of being understood by a general reader is only one factor to consider. If his audience is not the "general reader" then it's a less important factor. The fact that *morbid* and *macabre* may be more easily **mis**understood (as starwed pointed out, and I agree) could be a more important factor in choosing the best word for this situation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: in that case ... morticentric? But somehow it doesn't sound as good.

Comment: Forcing your readers to go consult a dictionary could be either (a) a smart move, or (b) a really dumb move, depending on who your readers are. If it's an essay for your teacher, you might impress one teacher, and tick another one off, or rouse suspicions of plagiarism.  If my 15 year old son wrote an essay with that word in it, I'd wonder where he got it from, since it makes the writer sound ultracrepidarian.  (Yup, go look that one up.)

Comment: @WarrenP Essayists and writers of fiction are allowed a certain amount of license; their products are often one and the same, after all. They're not engaged in [technical writing](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US), for the most part.

Comment: I seem to fail finding a single page including this word!

Comment: @Yuri Just entering _thanatocentric_ in Chrome's search box turns up a [number of pages](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=thanatocentric).

Comment: @Gnawme Oh, I see. I just searched it in this phrase **thanatocentric definition** and it kept correcting me into **ethnocentric**. I couldn't find it as an entry in dictionaries. Probably I need a technical one?

Answer (score 89):

The word **morbid** might work

> Characterized by or appealing to an abnormal and unhealthy interest in disturbing and unpleasant subjects, esp. death and disease. ([The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/morbid.aspx))

Or **macabre**

> having death as a subject : comprising or including a personalized representation of death  ([Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/macabre))

Although the dictionary definitions might suggest that macabre is a better fit, I would be more likely to use morbid in the example sentence.  Macabre often implies some connection to the more horrific aspects of death, while morbid suggests an unhealthy/depressed world view.   It's hard to truly judge the best fit without knowing more context!

Comment: "Morbid" was my first thought, too. Depending on the tone you want to achieve "necrophilic," used as a metaphor might add some punch.

Comment: Uhhh... Necrophilia means something else entirely

Comment: Morbid fits in well with the sentence.
"Furthermore, the consumerist society that envelops Siskind results in his morbid viewpoint of his surroundings."

Comment: My first thought was Morbid as well. Like the accepted answer, morbid is derived from an ancient language (Latin) word for death (mors). And litterally means focused on death.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: I don't think "morbid" is related to "mors". The original meaning is more related to disease than death; it's derived from a Latin word for disease "morbus" whose further etymology seems unclear. (The disease-focused meaning survives in related medical words such as "morbidity" and "comorbid(ity)" which refer to the incidence of a disease and  don't have anything to do with death.)

Answer (score 6):

The term you're looking for is

> **Morbid Obsession**

You will find this term has deep usage, [including in professional literature](http://www.wsps.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=75).

In the case of your fill-in-the-blank, you would say *"morbidly obsessive"*

Comment: "Anne is morbidly obsessive about her fears of being shot by a sniper on the street." In such a case, Anne is not at all obsessive about dead people or death in general. Rather, she is scared to death about being shot.

Comment: She is still morbidly obsessed.  The fact that it involves her own death is a secondary issue, but it doesn't change that she has an *obsession* with something related to *death*, and that this is a common usage.  We would be far less likely to call her fear-of-being-killed as being "macabre"

Comment: But you are no longer providing an answer that would apply to the spectrum the question asked for.

Comment: If you re-read the question, you'll see that your example to me is more off-topic than my answer. thx

Comment: Exactly - I agree with you totally. That is how the phrase "morbidly obsessed" is used.

Comment: "I happily shun the sun" does not mean I shun happiness. Likewise, "Tan-mom was morbidly obsessed with tanning" does not mean she was obsessed with the morbid, but being obsessed with tanning to the risk of her life. Notice that, the question asked for "obsession with idea of death", not "risking or fearing death for an obsession."

Comment: Your answer is like providing a word for "love to die" when someone asks for a word for "dying for love".

Answer (score 3):

Necroxxx is exemplified by the following words:

[Necrophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necrophilia), also called thanatophilia or necrolagnia, is the sexual attraction to corpses. It is classified as a paraphilia by the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of the American Psychiatric Association. The word is derived from the Greek words: νεκρός (nekros; "dead") and φιλία (philia; "love").

The dictionaries have a more complete definition:
[nec·ro·phil·i·a](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/necrophilic)  (nkr-fl-) also nec·rophi·lism (n-krf-lzm, n-)

> n.
>   1. Obsessive fascination with death and corpses.
>   2. Erotic attraction to or sexual contact with corpses.

Hence, necrophilic and necrophiliac.

The word is seek is probably [necromania](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/necromania)

> Medical Dictionary
>   necromania: nec·ro·ma·ni·a (něk'rə-mā'nē-ə, -mān'yə)
>   n. An abnormal tendency to dwell with longing on death.

Hence necromaniac, a person who indulges in necromania.

*Apparently, Necromania is also the name of a porn movie.*

If you are willing to coin a new word, it could be **necro-centric**.

If you don't mind being sarcastic, then coin the word **necroholic**, addicted to the subject of the dead.

Other necro words are: necromancy, necrology, necrological, necrologistics, necrophoresis.

> Furthermore, the consumerist society that envelops Siskind results in his necrophiliac/necromaniac/necro-centric viewpoint of his surroundings.

If I were you, I would use necro-centric.

Comment: Question - how did you happen upon necromania as a porn flick?

Comment: Keyed "necromania" into google search to get to dictionary record so that I copy the dictionary record here, but google also presented the porn movie as one of the results.

Comment: Save it for the judge, pervert! :D

Comment: Addendum: "The word YOU seek is probably necromania" rather than "The word IS seek is probably necromania".

Answer (score 3):

I have not read the book but to provide a bit of breadth to the discussion (and avoid pornography) I suggest "fatalistic."  From dictionary.com:

> Fatalistic: noun 
>   1. the acceptance of all things and events as inevitable; submission to fate: Her fatalism helped her to face death with stoic calm.  2. Philosophy . the doctrine that all events are subject to fate or inevitable predetermination.

Thus:

> Furthermore, the consumerist society that envelops Siskind results in [a] *fatalistic* view<strike>point</strike> of his surroundings.

This provides a bit of elegance to your sentence while also providing the hint that the character's viewpoint is a bit darker.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***thanatotic*** as an appropriate contextual adjective if you want to specifically refer to the concept of death as opposed to a general *fatalistic* worldview.

der. from Thanatos http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Thanatos in a manner similar to *eros*

By analogy you might also use ***mortal***, although common use of this term in other contexts might make it seem rather awkward in this sense.

***thanatomania***

This word [exists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanatomania)  and unlike the related *necromania*, does not have sexual connotations. No need for neologisms I guess.

Comment: I don't think "thanatotic" is properly formed. "Thanatos" and "Eros" both end in "os" in English, but in Greek the vowels are different, and they have different genitive stems.

Comment: ...Then again, apparently "chaotic" from "chaos" (Greek χάος, χάεος) is similarly malformed, so "thanatotic" may have some precedent.

Answer (score 0):

you can say [***eschatological***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eschatology?s=t) viewpoint. The context will make the meaning abundantly clear.